# How to set an initial value for an enumeration entry in Enterprise Architect using Java Automation API?

Tags: java, automation, enterprise-architect

I need to be able to set the initial value of an enumeration literal using the EA Java Automation API. Unfortunately I failed in finding out how this can be achieved in the manual. As I found out an Enumeration is actually represented by an **Element** in the EA object model. I am creating an element *elem* of type **Enumeration** and I am adding an **Attribute** to it by using the following code:

```
org.sparx.Attribute attr1 = elem.GetAttributes().AddNew("PTS_OFF", "Enum");
```

Then I am able to change certain properties of this attribute but I cannot find a setter for the initial value which is available in the GUI. 
Is there a dedicated API for this or I can do that with the GUI only (*by right-clicking on Enumeration entry->Properties->Details->Attributes->General->Initial Value*)? I am using EA v11.

Comment: How did you define the tagged value? Via MDG or view Default TVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I suspected it was easier than it looked. Thanks to Thomas Kilian who gave the idea of using the SQL for this task, I was able to perform a search and find out which field in the database exactly corresponds to the "Initial value" in the dialog. It turns out that the following code updates the initial value: 
`attr1.SetDefault("my initial value");`

Using SQL also works but it is the more complex way to go in this case as the attribute element actually contains a setter for this. Following Thomas's proposal, one can do the following:
`Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_attribute SET Default='my init value' where Name = 'PTS_OFF'");`

Comment: I got to used thinking this way after using EA for so many years. But sometimes I miss the more obvious solution ;-) Anyhow, I can't find the reference in the help for this method. Can you point it out? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. I opened _eaapi.jar_ and checked the methods provided by the **Attribute** class. I was not able to determine which method to use until I found out (using an SQL search) that the column name for the Initial value of an attribute is actually called **Default**. Then it suddenly became obvious... :-)

Comment: Good grief - I though you were talking about tagged values :-[ I shouldn't work too late.